# Angular Ajax temporaly variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json, angularjs

I'm trying of get the number of records return by ajax from a json file but when I'm trying of print the number the records outside the ".success block" I don't get the value that exits inside the ".success block"

Example:

```
var total = 0;
$http.get("json/noticias.json")
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.lista = response;
    total = response.noticias.length;
    alert(total);//Print 3
  });

alert(total);//Print 0
```

I need print 3 in the second one also.

Comment: which one prints first 0 or 3? I guess 0 right?

Comment: what is your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS uses a promise module called $q. So you have to use then() or catch()
This will get json data after success

```
var total = 0;
 $http.get("json/noticias.json") .success(function(response) {
 $scope.lista = response;
 response.total = response.noticias.length; ;
 alert(total);//Print 3 
 }).then( 
function( response ) {
 alert(response.total); //print 3 
});
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$http.get()` is an asynchronous call, which means the execution flow doesn't stop for `$http.get()` to  fetch all the values and execute the logic inside `.success()` function and then move to next sequence of events.

The execution flow carries on and next statements are executed while the `$http()` call fetches the data and `.success()` is invoked. Hence, you get 0 in `alert()` first and then 3. So at the time when `alert()` outside `$http()` call is executed, the value of `total` is still `0` as `total` has not yet been updated in the `.success()` callback.

You should use promises and $q to handle success and error conditions of `$http` call.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try your solution although I already got my objective working inside .success()

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the length to the `total` property of the scope, then you can access it outside the success method and bind it to your html element. But note that you'll be able to access the updated value of `total`, once the response is available.  The following should solve your problem:

```
$scope.total = 0;
$http.get("json/noticias.json")
  .success(function(response) {
    $scope.lista = response;
    $scope.total = response.noticias.length;
    alert($scope.total);//Print 3
  });

alert($scope.total);//Print 0
```